# How to export Load Balancer log to BigQuery in Real Time?

Tags: google-bigquery, load-balancing, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

We are trying to export all the http request to our google load balancer into big query. Unfortunately we notice that data arrives 3 minutes later to BigQuery.

Starting from this tutorial:https://cloud.google.com/solutions/serverless-pixel-tracking

1. We created a Load Balancer that points to a pixel.png on a public storage
2. Created a sink to export all log to Pub/Sub
3. Created DataFlow with streaming insert pub/sub to BigQuery Table with provided template
4. Table is partitioned on date and has a cluster column on hour and minutes.

After we scale to 1000 request per seconds we noticed that data was delayed by 2 or 3 minutes

`SELECT * FROM DATASET ORDER BY Timestamp desc Limit 100`

this query will be executed with few seconds but the last result is 3 minutes old

Comment: TIPS: if you works with real time data make sure that server clock is sync with google server.

Answer (score 0):

I am exporting log for a lot of different resources into BigQuery directly without using dataflow or pub/sub and I can see them in realtime. If yuo do not need to do some special pre-processing in dataflow, you might want to try to export directly into [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create) and remove other stuff in between that introduce latency.

Comment: we do preprocessing but just to remove some column of load balancer row data so dataflow is mandatory

Comment: If you do it for privacy you could build a view on top of the table with all column and give access only to a specific set of columns. If you do it for the cost you could roll up the table at the end of the day and restrict access to the today table with a view.
If you really really need to use dataflow maybe you have to tune the machine count or the time window.